# Dynamically change <div> background-image with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, url, dynamic, href

I'm looking for some help writing a javascript snippet that will DYNAMICALLY update a div style= "background-image:url..." to match the a href above it. This is on a portfolio website, so this is a gallery where all the images are live at once. I need the snippet to run through each individual `a href` and nested `div` underneath it and have them match, unique to each image (Don't want a page of the same picture 20 times)
 I'm just starting to learn JS, so I've been struggling with this one. Here's the html.

```
<a id ="tobematched" href="imgs/galleryphotos/1.jpg">
```

This href should from above should be copied to the div style url below.

```
<div id ="matcher" class="img-container" style="background-image: url('imgs/notcorrect/currently.jpg');"></div>
</a>
```

This is what it looks like as a whole...

```
<a id ="tobematched" href="imgs/galleryphotos/1.jpg">
    <div id ="matcher" class="img-container" style="background-image: url('imgs/notcorrect/currently.jpg');"></div>
</a>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

This is what I'm thinking, so far...

```
function abc() {
    var a = document.getElementById("tobematched").
    var b = document.getElementById("matcher").style.backgroundImage;

                        }
```

Not sure where to go from here, since I don't know how to grab the href... I think I'm on the right track.

Comment: Are you looking for pure JS or does jquery work?

Comment: pure JS would be best... I think.  I have a few different things I've tried so far, mostly with getElementById... I figured I could grab the href that way, but that doesn't seem to work. WebStorm doesn't like href. It is cool with ".style.backgroundImage" however. So I can grab the div's "style", but not the a href... if that makes sense

Comment: see the changes to the original post. let's see how i'm doing... haha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a combination of [querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) and the `.href` property to get what you need:

```
var targetDiv = document.querySelector('#matcher');
var url = targetDiv.parentNode.href;
targetDiv.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + url + ')';
```

Alternatively you can use:

```
var url = document.querySelector('#tobematched').href
```

This second option does not depend on the structure of the document, but causes JS to look through the whole document again.

If you were using jQuery:

```
var url = $('#tobematched')attr('href');
$('#matcher').css('background-image', 'url(' + url + ')');
```

[Live Example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jWxJoE)

---

Edit: As per the further description by OP in the comments, here is the code you actually need:

```
var targetDivs = document.querySelectorAll('.img-container');

for (var i = 0; i < targetDivs.length; i++) {
  var url = targetDivs[i].parentNode.href;
  targetDivs[i].style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + url + ')';
}
```

Comment: Would this work if I have the same structure of code repeated a few lines later?  This is for a gallery I'm working on. For each image, the "matcher" needs to match the <a href> it's nested under.

Comment: if you are using `id` to match, it will be unique to each element, since `id` properties must be unique.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, each time I have another image, I need a different and unique "id" then. Is there a better way to do this? Thanks for your help by the way.

Comment: Maybe using a `class` instead of an `id` would be best

Comment: it depends when you want this to happen. do all of the images exist at once? when do you want this snippet to run?

Comment: They all exist at once. I'd like the snippet to run as soon as the page is loaded. Picture a portfolio. The `<a href="someimagefile.jpg>` is what pops up when the image is clicked on. The `<div style="background-image:url....` is what is showing on the page itself... AKA the image that is initially seen and clicked on.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working. I understand the logic behind it, but the `var url` does not pass to the `targetDivs[i].style.backgroundImage` as it should...

Comment: you can see in my live example how it works, compare to your code. try putting some debuggers around your code and seeing if url is getting the right value and if targetDivs is also getting the right value. check your spelling. not much more I can do! please accept the answer if it helped

Comment: It worked! I just had some spelling that was off. I appreciate your help!